# How does a control determine which DataContext to use?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

I have a Window which contains a control.

The control has a viewmodel set as the DataContext object.

The Window object has its own ViewModel set as the DataContext.

If I bind a property of the control inside the Window XAML how does it determine which DataContext to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data context is resolved using bottom approach. It means that first the property is searched in the control itself, then the parent of control, Then parent of patent and so on utill it finds the property or reaches at the root window.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I would like to bind a property of the control to a property of the window data context?

Comment: You can use element name property present in bind attribute. Just set the ElementName to name of the window after the Path

Comment: What you call "bottom approach" is actually called [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible ways:

1) You can decide from the code behind what would be the data context: `DataContext = this;`  <- for example

2) you can do it through the DictionaryResources which you can write in the App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SolutionsToRecoverViewModel}">
                <someView:SolutionsRecovery/>
            </DataTemplate>
```

3) you can create a dictionary file buy yourself (and write the las xaml code) and in the initalization of the window register it:

```
public class someClass
    {
        private static bool _registerUIMapping = false;

    public CopyNPasteBottemViewModel()
    {
        if (!_registerUIMapping)
        {
            ResourceDictionary MyResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            MyResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("somePath/UIMapping.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(MyResourceDictionary);
            _registerUIMapping = true;
        }
    }

    private bool _doThisForTheNextConflictProperty = false;

    public bool DoThisForTheNextConflict
    {
        get 
        {
            return _doThisForTheNextConflictProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _doThisForTheNextConflictProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DoThisForTheNextConflict");
        }
    }

}
```